# Где хранятся куски union? C (Си)

Tags: c, память, union

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

union IFC {
    int i;
    float f;
    char c;
};

int main(void) {
    union IFC ifc = {.f = 3.14};
    printf("Union's float is %.2f\n", ifc.f); // 3.14
    ifc.i = 2;
    printf("Union's integer is %d\n", ifc.i); // 2
    ifc.c = 'A';
    printf("Union's character is %c\n", ifc.c); // A
    printf("Union's float is %.2f\n", ifc.f); // 0.00
    return 0;
}
```

Как данный код работает на уровне памяти вычислительной машины? Откуда берётся значение `0.00` у `inf.f` в то время, когда в union'e используется `inf.c`? Я понимаю, что один union занимает в любом допустимом для него состоянии (в моём случае `int`/`float`/`char`) одинаковое количество байт. Но ведь эти байты хранят только одно значение. Почему же, если в данный момент времени там хранится символ 'A', я всё равно могу обратиться к union'у за вещественным числом `inf.f`? Хоть оно и не то, что я когда-то задавал, хоть оно и равняется всегда нулю, оно всё же возвращается. Как это работает?

Comment: «хоть оно и равняется всегда нулю» — не проверял, но вероятно не нулю, а очень-очень маленькому числу, которые вы округляете и из-за этого видите ноль

Comment: Часто `union`ы используют как 'быстрый' конвертор одного в другое, по причине что память для всех 'конвертируемых' элементов одна и та-же.

Comment: @NewView - нельзя делать такую конвертацию, потому как последовательность "запись поля A" - "чтение поля B" приводит к неопределенному поведению.

Comment: @gbg, вероятно я чего то не знаю, но union именно для этого и придназначен - "запись поля A" - "чтение поля B" - иначе в чем смысл его использования? Как пример, типовые реализации хешей md5, sha1-512 и тд именно так и используют union'ы

Comment: Да, и конечно очевидно, что данные должны совпадать по размеру, но это уже частности и детали, очевидно использование в следующем виде: `union { uint8_t[12] buf; uint32_t a,b,c; }` тогда при чтении в union.buf размером 12, мы получаем сразу 3 значения uint32, данный метод используется почти во всех графических библиотеках при обработки пикселей/RGB/ итд

Comment: @NewView - после таких извращений, код становится прибит гвоздями к конкретному процессору/компилятору. Чтите разработчиков стандарта языка, а не классных пацанов: http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Ru-pun  Note

Unfortunately, unions are commonly used for type punning. We don’t consider “sometimes, it works as expected” a strong argument.

Comment: @gbg: Вы перепутали С и С++. В С++ это - неопределенное поведение. Этот же вопрос о языке С и явно помечен тэгом [C]. В языке С такое использование `union` давно официально разрешено стандартом языка. Что в вопросе по С делает ваша ссылка на С++ guidelines - не ясно.

Comment: @NewView: смысл использования union заключается в первую и главную очередь в экономии памяти путем переиспользования ее для хранения разных данных в разное время. Именно для этого предназначены и всегда были предназначены union. Одновременной работы с несколькими полями для этого не нужно. Использование union для переинтерпретации памяти - побочная второстепенная функциональность union, к тому же запрещенная в С++.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Во-первых, язык С гарантирует, что все поля union имеют один и тот же адрес, совпадающий с адресом всего union. Практически это означает, что все поля union хранятся с перекрытием по одному и тому же адресу в памяти. Размер union будет равен размеру его максимального поля (плюс, возможно, какие-то дополнительные неиспользуемые байты, добавленные для целей выравнивания).

Во-вторых, язык С говорит, что назначение значения какому-то полю union приводит неиспользуемые этим полем байты в *неопределенное состояние*. По этой причине, так как поле `char c` на вашей платформе скорее всего имеет меньший размер, чем поле `float f`, нет смысла читать поле `f` после назначения значения полю `c` - это приведет в общем случае к неопределенному поведению. На практике вполне разумно предположить, что даже в рамках одной программы одна запись значения `c` может затронуть все байты вашего union, а другая - только байты собственно `c`.

Union в С можно использовать для переинтерпретации объектного представления одного типа   как объектного представления другого типа, но это обычно имеет смысл только для типов одинакового размера.

Простой эксперимент с GCC показывает (https://godbolt.org/z/nphzx-), что в неоптимизированном коде ваш union хранится в памяти и изменение значения поля `c` изменяет лишь один байт памяти, а вот в оптимизированном коде весь union хранится в регистре процессора `esi` и запись значения поля `c` переписывает всё содержимое регистра, т.е. фактически обнуляет все "лишние" байты union.

Answer (score 10):

Биты всех полей занимают одну и ту же память.

Их интерпретация зависит от имени (типа) поля, к которому вы обращаетесь.

Т.о. изменяя любое поле вы одновременно изменяете и все остальные.

Answer (score 5):

> Как это работает?

Очень часто *union* используются для работы с "железом" - чтение, проверка и запись бит в слово. Допустим, Вы пишите драйвер для устройства, который должен работать с множеством регистров этого устройства, а каждый регистр - совокупность множества битовых полей. Проще всего это реализуется так:

```
union RESISTER_1 {
    u32 int_value;
    struct {
            uint field1 : 1;
            uint field2 : 7;
            uint field3 : 1
            . . .
    } bit_fields;
} xyz;
```

Тогда читать/писать значение регистра Вы сможете используя поле размером в слово (*xyz.int_value*), а работать с битами - используя битовые поля (*xyz.bit_fields.field2*).

Answer (score -1):

Вот схема по которой все очень наглядно.

```
union container {
    short s;
    int i;
    float f;
    char c;
    double d;
    long l;
    long long ll;
};
```

схема расположения в памяти:

```
container
______________________________
|char|                       |
|   short  |                 |
|       int        |         |
|       float      |         |
|          double            |
|          long long         |
|          long              |
|  1 |  2  | 4     |   8     |
______________________________
```