# Битовые поля. Найти два старших разряда

Tags: c, битовые-операции, объединение

Есть программа, которая определяет два старших разряда двоичного числа:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct r
{
    unsigned int x : 8;
};

union code
{
    struct r p;
    struct {
        unsigned a0 : 1;
        unsigned a1 : 1;
        unsigned a2 : 1;
        unsigned a3 : 1;
        unsigned a4 : 1;
        unsigned a5 : 1;
        unsigned a6 : 1;
        unsigned a7 : 1;
    } byte;
};
void main(void) {
    int x;
    scanf_s("%d", &x);
    while (x < 0) {
        printf("\nError: invalid number\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &x);
    }
    struct r center = { x };
    union code c;
    c.p = center;
    printf("\nNumber: %d\n", x);
    if (c.byte.a7 != 0) {
        printf("Two highest discharges: %d %d", c.byte.a7, c.byte.a6);
    }
    else {
        if (c.byte.a6 != 0) {
            printf("Two highest discharges: %d %d", c.byte.a6, c.byte.a5);
        }
        else {
            if (c.byte.a5 != 0) {
                printf("Two highest discharges: %d %d", c.byte.a5, c.byte.a4);
            }
            else {
                if (c.byte.a4 != 0) {
                    printf("Two highest discharges: %d %d", c.byte.a4, c.byte.a3);
                }
                else {
                    if (c.byte.a3 != 0) {
                        printf("Two highest discharges: %d %d", c.byte.a3, c.byte.a2);
                    }
                    else {
                        if (c.byte.a2 != 0) {
                            printf("Two highest discharges: %d %d", c.byte.a2, c.byte.a1);
                        }
                        else {
                            if (c.byte.a1 != 0) {
                                printf("Two highest discharges: %d %d", c.byte.a1, c.byte.a0);
                            }
                            else {
                                printf("Two highest discharges: %d %d", 0, c.byte.a0);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("7 \t 6 \t 5 \t 4 \t 3 \t 2 \t 1 \t 0 \n");
    printf("%d \t %d \t %d \t %d \t %d \t %d \t %d \t %d \n", c.byte.a7, c.byte.a6, c.byte.a5, c.byte.a4, 
c.byte.a3, c.byte.a2, c.byte.a1, c.byte.a0);
}
```

Вывод: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
**Можно ли как-нибудь реализовать это без такого количества "if/else"**, вообще ничего в голову не приходит

Comment: Нельзя ли сформулировать другими словами, что значит `Найти два старших разряда`? (Кстати, термин discharge тут никак не подходит)

Comment: Самое простое, в цикле сдвигаете число влево до тех пор пока 8й разряд данного байта не станет равным 1. после чего 8й и 7й разряды - искомое. (при счете разрядов с 1)

Comment: @MBo как в примере число 100011, вывести на экран 2 старших бита числа, за свой elementary извиняюсь, если подскажите более корректный перевод, буду благодарен

Comment: @Mike надо конкретно с битовыми полями работать

Comment: Тогда говорите о старшем **ненулевом** (единичном) бите. Просто "старший" обычно означает самый левый бит конкретного типа (восьмой, шестнадцатый и т.д.). Называть - просто биты `bits`.

Comment: А где это требование в вопросе указано ? мы должны угадывать какие требования к решению представлены ? И боюсь, что от if никуда не уйти, потому что эти битовые поля все равно надо явно по именам перебирать и цикла никакого не сделаешь

Comment: @Mike понял, вопрос некорректно сформулировал, но спасибо за помощь :)

Comment: У Вас есть наложенный на эти битовые поля ```int```. В цикле сдвигайте его вправо, пока оно не станет меньше 4, соответственно в нем останутся только два значащих разряда: нулевой и первый. Их и выводите.

Comment: Два старших разряда 8-битного числа 01100000 какие? 01 или 11? А то из вашего условия это непонятно... А если число 00000001? Тогда какие?

Answer (score 3):

Судя по вашему коду, вам нужно [это](https://ideone.com/3nWW8y)?

```
void two_bits(unsigned int x, unsigned char * b1, unsigned char * b2)
{
    if (x < 2) { *b1 = 0; *b2 = x&1; return; }
    while(x >= 4) x >>=1;
    *b2 = (unsigned char)(x&1); *b1 = (unsigned char)(x>>1);
}
```

Или еще проще:

```
void two_bits(unsigned int x, unsigned char * b1, unsigned char * b2)
{
    while(x != (x & 3) ) x >>=1;
    *b2 = (unsigned char)(x&1); *b1 = (unsigned char)(x>>1);
}
```

Comment: Кстати, а зачем в первом варианте  ```if```? Кмк, можно его спокойно убрать, или я что-то упускаю?

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Можно. Но я это сообразил уже потом :)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Спасибо, человеческие языки — не моя специальность :) Хотя, может, так и было задумано? Два укуса? :)

Answer (score 0):

Я уже писал на эту тему:

[Где хранятся куски union? C (Си)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/925941/%d0%93%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8-union-c-%d0%a1%d0%b8/925996#925996)

Вкратце... Для того, что бы анализировать байт, слово или ещё что по битам, проще всего использовать структуру *union*, содержащую два поля:

1. Анализируемое значение
2. Структуру, описывающую разбиение на битовые поля

Приблизительно вот так:

```
union RESISTER_1 {
    u16 int_value;
    struct {
            uint field1 : 1; // Нулевой бит
            uint field2 : 1; // Первый бит
            uint field3 : 14 // Оставшиеся 14 бит
    } bit_fields;
} xyz;
```

Тогда анализируемое значение Вы можете поместить в структуру так:

```
xyz.int_value = <Анализируемое значение>;
```

А проверять биты можно так:

```
if (xyz.bit_fields.field1 == 0) // Проверка нулевого бита значения
```